# ASP.net MVC - Sharing partials between areas

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-areas

is there some way to share a partial razor view between areas?

For example a login partial, it is found if i use `@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")` but the URLs `Html.ActionLink` generates are local to the calling area (even though the partial itself is not part of the area).

```
_LoginPartial.cshtml is in /Views/Shared/_LoginPartial.cshtml
Calling view is inside /Areas/Somearea/Views

Links generated are like: http://example.com/Somearea/Account/Login
But should always be: http://example.com/Account/Login
```

Partial view source:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
    <text>Welcome <b>@Context.User.Identity.Name</b>!
    [ @Html.ActionLink(@Messages.Logout, "Logout", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
    @:[ @Html.ActionLink(@Messages.Login, "Login", "Account") ]
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can specify the area (or lack of one) in the `ActionLink()` method:

```
Html.ActionLink(@Messages.Logout, "Logout", "Account", new { Area = "" }, new{})
```

This will ensure the link does not resolve to a URL within the current area.